# Techniques to calculate the cost of change in software engineering

Tags: estimation, requirements

There is a bunch of techniques to do software *estimation*.
Now given a piece of software, is there some methods/techniques to evaluate the **cost of change** of an already implemented requirement ?

Comment: **Expert estimation**. You should ask your developers to make estimation. I think this is the only way to do it.

Comment: Why would the estimating techniques be any different?

Answer (score 4):

There are several quasi-scientific methods- Look up COCOMO and Function Point Analysis - However there are massive overheads, financially, procedurally, intellectually and practically in deploying these (or presumably) any other method.

For all but the largest development projects it is likely that your best bet will be to work through the estimation process with the development team, as has been suggested in comments.